# How can we retrieve the custom fields on line items to another object line items?

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem

I would like to ask you how to retrieve Custom fields on line item between 2 customs object . for example : I have

> Object Sales order Line Items  : customer description - product - product code

So on Sales order page , I create a button Create Delivery note ( related to sales order ) , when I open the Delivery note and on the Delivery note line items I can retrieve the fields Product - Customer Description - product code - product .
My problem is when I added another field on sales order Linte item (number Line item ) and do the same process on delivery note Line item , I can' t retrieve this field like the others , even if I create a lookup ( sales order) type .

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the essence of your existing solution and highlight what is not working. As it stands now, your question is not sufficiently illuminating

Comment: Julio -- please move the image into the post - you can edit your post and add images

Comment: @crop1645 >> Sorry , I edited my question by adding the image . I don't yet resolve the problem . Thanks

Comment: Julio - I echo my original comment - there's not enough here to provide assistance.